# Share a host folder to an alpine image running in qemu

Tags: qemu, alpine

I have try to run an alpine Linux in an emulated environment this way:

```
$ wget https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.16/releases/x86/alpine-netboot-3.16.1-x86.tar.gz
```

I have untar the archive and run:

```
qemu-system-i386 -m 256 -kernel boot/vmlinuz-lts -initrd boot/initramfs-lts -append "console=ttyS0 ip=dhcp alpine_repo=http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main/" -virtfs local,path=/xxxx/mylocalfolder,mount_tag=mytag1,security_model=passthrough
```

I want to share a folder between the host machine and the emulated computer (see virtfs option). Here is what i've type in the qemu virtual machine:

```
mount -t 9p -o trans=virtio mytag1 /mnt
```

I get this error:

> mount: mounting mytag1 on /mnt failed: No such device

I do not understand why. Any idea ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: samba and nfs are your friends ;)

Comment: Not easy because I need to configure network for that (my host has a dhcp ip)

Comment: even dhcp can be set to a static release, that's no reason

Comment: Yes but in my case i do not have the control of the dhcp server

Comment: then you are not running with a business environment and or administrative rights. that leads to the fact, that it would be off topic on serverfault.com but might be on topic on superuser.com

Comment: I have control on this server but not on the whole organisation. The host IP may change and i have no control on that.

Comment: this sounds for me that you are not allowed to do so. which end that you are imho are not a business administrator, but more a end user and therefore relates to superuser.com